# how to create incremental files with version in shell

Tags: shell

how to create files dynamically when i run shell script.
Intially in the `/tmp` folder i need to check if file like(`CFT_AH-120_v1.txt`) exist in tmp folder else create `CFT_AH-120_v1.txt`. Next time when i run shell script it should create `CFT_AH-120_v2.txt` and in each run it should increment the version number of the file.

In tmp folder i should have files like

```
CFT_AH-120_v1.txt
CFT_AH-120_v2.txt
CFT_AH-120_v3.txt
```

i will get `CFT_AH-120` from variable dynamically.

```
#!/bin/bash
export filename
temp=$(find CFT_AH-120-V* |  sort -V | tail -1)
if [ -e $temp ]
then    echo "ok"
    echo $temp
    fname="${temp%.*}"
    echo $fname
    temp1="${temp%[[:digit:]]*}$((${temp##*[[:alpha:]]} + 1))"
    echo $temp1
    touch $temp1 ".txt"
else
    touch CFT_AH-120-V1.txt
    echo "nok"
fi
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the exact requirement for you. As per my understanding this is a simple way of approach.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_temp=$(find . -name "CFT_AH-120-V*" -type f |  sort -V | tail -1)
echo $temp
if [ -z "$temp" ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
else
    num_temp=$(echo $temp | cut -d '-' -f3- | sed 's/V//')
    num_value_incr=$(expr $new_temp + 1)
    touch "CFT_AH-120-V$num_value_incr"
    echo "New file created!"
fi
```

**Note:** This code search for the largest value of the **"V"....number.... (eg.***V120)** and increment based on that value and also the intermediate number wont be increment. If you need the missing numbers to be created, then the logic for this code needs to be changed.

Hope this might help you!

Comment: Any reason to use the old-fashioned `$(expr)` stuff? `bash` supports a much nicer arithmetic context like this: `((num_value_incr=new_temp+1))`

Comment: @Mark Setchell - Any way we can prefer, both works fine.